# Is there a clean way I can access an instance parent's instance?

Tags: javascript, class, parent-child

I wish to access a parent instance from a child instance:

```
class Child {
    constructor(props) {
        // how do I access the parent Container instance from here?
    }
}

class Container {
    childInstance = new Child()
}
```

I cannot find a clean way to do this. The best way I found was to pass `this` to the child instance: `new Child(this)`, but I find it heavy. Is there a simpler way that would not require me to manually pass `this` to every `child` I instanciate? Something like this for example:

```
class Child {
    constructor(props) {
        this.parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing `this` to the child is the correct way to do it. If you find you are passing `this` through a whole chain of children and grandchildren, you might look into the `Singleton` pattern. This allows a parent to be reached from anywhere in the child hierarchy.

Comment: @Kokodoko , thanks, I'll go with with Singleton pattern, I find it prettier. My classes will all extend a base class in which the Container instance is set as property. That way, all classes can have access to the Container instance by extending the base class.

Comment: @Kokodoko No, the singleton pattern is a bad idea here, it doesn't allow you to have multiple containers

Comment: @papillon "*My classes will all extend a base class in which the Container instance is set as property.*" - yes, that's a good idea (the base class should be called `ContainerElement`), but that's not the singleton pattern

Comment: @Bergi I think in my case the parent container makes sense as a singleton since it must only be instanciated once. It will never be instanciated twice.